# FFMPEG scale, zoom, and concat filter

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg for android to produce video with mp4 format. I'm having trouble getting this command to work in FFMPEG, basically I am trying to add two images, scale them, add zoom effect, and finally concat the result into one video file. I have done something like this :

```
ffmpeg 
-t 8 -i image1.png
-t 8 -i image2.png
-filter_complex
[0:v]scale=720:720[scl1]; [1:v]scale=720:720[scl2];
[scl1]zoompan=z=if(lte(zoom, 1.0), 1.55, max(1.001, zoom - 0.0010)):d=205, fade=t=out:st=7:d=1[v0];
[scl2]zoompan=z=if(lte(zoom, 1.0), 1.55, max(1.001, zoom - 0.0010)):d=205, fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=7:d=1[v1];
[v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0, format=yuv420p[v] -map [v] outputVideo.mp4
```

Been tinkering with this command for a while but still can't get it to work and I got error :

```
Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 1280x720, SAR 0:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1280x720, SAR 45:31)
[Parsed_concat_7 @ 0xf0d77600] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_7
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg 
-i image1.png
-i image2.png
-filter_complex
[0:v]scale=720:720,setsar=1[scl1]; [1:v]scale=720:720,setsar=1[scl2];
[scl1]zoompan=z=if(lte(zoom, 1.0), 1.55, max(1.001, zoom - 0.0010)):s=720x720:d=205, fade=t=out:st=7:d=1[v0];
[scl2]zoompan=z=if(lte(zoom, 1.0), 1.55, max(1.001, zoom - 0.0010)):s=720x720:d=205, fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=7:d=1[v1];
[v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0, format=yuv420p[v] -map [v] outputVideo.mp4
```

When using zoompan on single images, set duration (in frames) in the filter, not on the input.

Your highlighted problem was due to the scale filter adjusting the aspect ratio. The setsar filter makes them the same.